# check for data completeness oracle etl

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, etl

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we check for complete data load and validate boundary values as part of the ETL testing process. (The two tables could be T1 and T2). Please let me know a sample query.

Thanks, Santosh

Answer (score 0):

To verify data completeness, perform following validations-:

• Ensure that all expected data is loaded into target table.
• Compare record counts between source and target.
• Check for any rejected records
• Check data should not be truncated in the column of target tables

You can write simple minus queries to check the same-:

`((Select [column1], [column2]…,[column n] from t1
Minus
Select [column1], [column2]…,[column n] from t2)
Union
(Select [column1], [column2]…,[column n] from t2
Minus
Select [column1], [column2]…,[column n] from t1`

To check Boundry Values -:

```
Select * FROM t1 WHERE id NOT BETWEEN x AND y;
```